# Excel VBA - Looking for ways to simplify loop

Tags: vba, excel, foreach

I recently made a loop that takes the string in each cell, searches for a "_" in the string, and if there is one cuts off that bit and any character after it. Looking at the code I realized it might be too elaborate and could be shortened or simplified, but I'm not quite sure how to do so. Is there a way to make this bit of code more efficient?

```
Sub Name_Change()

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

Dim tg_row As Integer
tg_row = 1

For Each nm_cl In Range("Table1[Name]")
    If InStr(1, nm_cl, "_", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        Range("Table1[Name]").Cells(tg_row, 1).Value = nm_cl.Value
    Else
        Range("Table1[Name]").Cells(tg_row, 1) = _
                Left(nm_cl, InStr(1, nm_cl, "_", vbTextCompare) - 1)
    End If
    tg_row = tg_row + 1
Next nm_cl

End Sub
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: About how big is the range `Table1[Name]`?  less than 65K rows?

Comment: It changes, but I haven't seen it more than 5K rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A first attempt at optimizing this would be to note that you are calling `InStr` multiple times.  You can speed things up by computing it once, and storing the result.

Along with that I would note that presumably `Range("Table1[Name]")` only has one column (otherwise you would be overwriting the first column with data from the other columns).  So, you can replace `Range("Table1[Name]").Cells(tg_row, 1)` with `nm_cl`.  In doing this, we notice the redundant statement of `nm_cl.Value = nm_cl.Value` can be removed.  This leads to the following code:

```
Sub Name_Change()

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

Dim index As Long

For Each nm_cl In Range("Table1[Name]")
    index = InStr(1, nm_cl, "_", vbTextCompare)
    If index <> 0 Then
        nm_cl = Left(nm_cl, index - 1)
    End If
Next nm_cl

End Sub
```

If you need more efficiency, beyond this, you can load your data into a variant by using

```
dim data as Variant
data = Range("Table1[Name]").Value
```

process all of your data within VBA, and then put it back to the worksheet using

```
Range("Table1[Name]").Value = data
```

This will increase your speed, as transfering data between Excel and VBA is slow and this means you will have 1 read and 1 write, instead of 1 read and 1 write *per line*, but it will require a (minor) rewrite of your algorithm as the syntax for working with an array within a variant is different from working with ranges.  Note that this will not work if you go beyond the 65536 rows.  I beleive that it is a legacy constraint from Excel 2003 and earlier.

Comment: Yes, `Range("Table1[Name]")` is just one column in Table1. I really like this approach, but for some reason when I substitute this code in, it just doesn't work. Not even an error pops up. I tried replacing your `If` with an `If Not` because maybe it didn't like the "does not equal" symbol, but that didn't work either...

Comment: I'm not sure.  It works for me.  Have you tried stepping through and seeing what `nm_cl`, and `index` are at each step?

Comment: I tried each step, and it looked like the values were out of sync? So I changed `nm_cl = Left(nm_cl, index - 1)` to `nm_cl.Value = Left(nm_cl, index - 1)` and then it worked. Not sure why it got out of sync, maybe because the `[Name]` range starts at row=2?

Comment: Excuse me good sir, have you heard of [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

You could adjust your loop to only modify the cells that contain "_".

```
If Not InStr(1, nm_cl, "_", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
    Range("Table1[Name]").Cells(tg_row, 1) = _
            Left(nm_cl, InStr(1, nm_cl, "_", vbTextCompare) - 1)
End If
```

EDIT:

Here's a working example that includes @Degustaf's suggestions. Just change the name of the range to fit your worksheet.

```
Sub Name_Change()

Dim selectedRange As Range
Dim rangeData As Variant 'Array containing data from specified range
Dim col As Long 'Selected column from range
Dim row As Long 'Selected row from range
Dim cellValue As String 'Value of selected cell
Dim charPosition As Long 'Position of underscore

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

Set selectedRange = Range("YOUR-NAMED-RANGE-HERE")

If selectedRange.Columns.Count > 65536 Then
    MsgBox "Too many columns!", vbCritical
ElseIf selectedRange.Rows.Count > 65536 Then
    MsgBox "Too many rows!", vbCritical
Else
    rangeData = selectedRange.Value
    If UBound(rangeData, 1) > 0 And UBound(rangeData, 2) > 0 Then
        'Iterate through rows
        For row = 1 To UBound(rangeData, 1)
            'Iterate through columns
            For col = 1 To UBound(rangeData, 2)
                'Get value of cell
                cellValue = CStr(rangeData(row, col))
                'Get position of underscore
                charPosition = InStr(1, cellValue, "_", vbTextCompare)
                'Update cell data stored in array if underscore exists
                If charPosition <> 0 Then
                    rangeData(row, col) = Left(cellValue, charPosition - 1)
                End If
            Next col
        Next row
        'Overwrite range with array data
        selectedRange.Value = rangeData
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This is great! I want to try to fuse your approach with @Degustaf but I've been having hiccups getting it to work, and by hiccups I mean it's not working

Answer (score 0):

You could use a user defined function to return the truncated strings in cells.
The Worksheet-function could look like:

```
 Public function truncateAt( s as String) as string
     dim pos as integer         
     pos = instr (1, s,"_")
     If pos> 0 then
         truncateAt= left (s, pos)
     Else
         truncateAt= s
     End If
 End function
```